# JavaEE WebProject request attribute or JPA entity seems to be cached

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am very new to JavaEE. I experienced a strange behavior that I could not explain to myself.

### explanation:

I have an index.jsp which contains a form with a search term and a submit button.

On POST I call a Servlet which handles the doPost method. In that method I obtain a JPA EntityManager and get the instance of an Item-entity stored in the database by id.

The resulting item is then stored as a request attribute. (which, if I read my book properly, is only valid in THE request that I'm currently in)

At last, I use the request dispatcher to forward back to the index.jsp.

In the index.jsp there is an expression which either outputs the item's title or an empty string, if request attribute is not set.

### effects:

When I have an item in my database which has the exact id that I find via EM, everything works fine. On the index.jsp, after POST request, the item's title is shown.

Then I deleted the database item.

However, in subsequent requests, instead of showing an empty string, the title of the item (which is already deleted) will be shown.

This is a behavior I did not expect and can not explain. Is there any kind of caching in place? If I rebuild and redeploy my application then an empty string is shown again.

### So my questions:

- if I store a request attribute, is it cached until next request? (well, It should not if I understood the request scope)
- is there a caching in the JPA framework? Or is the entity itself cached/reused?

### source code:

*index.jsp*

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Lagerverwaltung</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Lagerverwaltung</h1>
        <p>
            <strong>Suche:</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
            <c:out value="${title}" default="" />
        </p>
        <form method="POST" action="search" name="search_form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>nach Titel:</td><td><input type="text" name="search_title" placeholder="Titel ..." value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>nach Artikelnummer:</td><td><input type="text" name="search_article_nr" placeholder="Artikelnummer ..." /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>nach Beschreibung</td><td><input type="text" name="search_description" placeholder="Beschreibung ..." /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="search_submit" value="Suchen" /></td><td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

*SearchServlet.java*

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    try {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        ut.begin();
        Item it = em.find(Item.class, 1);
        ut.commit();

        request.setAttribute("title", it.getTitle());
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SearchServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you deleting the item? Which JPA provider do you use? Some JPA providers have caching turned on by default.

Comment: Just as a side note: if you're in the context of JavaEE I'd use an EJB to access the entity manager. You can let the container inject the entity manager into the EJB and get transaction handling automagically.

Comment: I delete the item directly in the database using Sequel Pro

Comment: JPA provider is Eclipse Link

Comment: In addition to Nick's comment: what he refers to would be the second level cache which would still contain the entity.

Comment: By default Eclipselink will cache the last 100 items. Deleting the item directly in the database will not update this cache.

Comment: Try `em.refresh()` to make the entity manager (try to) load the entity again or disable second level cache (the JPA provider won't check the database if an entity is in the second level cache unless it sees a need to do so, either by altering database contents via the entity manager or telling it to refresh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my *persistence.xml* I added the folowing to my persistence unit:

```
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
```

This disables the cache and it works like expected now.